# Moving files across folders in the same S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In the same bucket I've folders named Backup1 and Backup2.

Files in Backup1 folder transition from S3 Standard storage to Glacier after 5 days.

Now from the S3 console, if I want to copy some of these files from Backup1 folder to Backup2:

1. Will I incur any charges if these files are less than 90 days old?
2. Will the copy be done from Glacier to Glacier or will it be from Glacier to S3 Standard?
3. Since this involves file copy from Glacier, will it be time consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's worth mentioning that there have been some recent updates to Amazon S3:

- It is now possible to upload directly to the Glacier storage class, rather than having to specify a Lifecycle rule. This is good for files you want to archive immediately (not necessarily your use-case).
- There is a [new S3 Intelligent-Tiering Storage Class](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-intelligent-tiering/) that will automatically move objects in/out of Glacier based on usage patterns.

**Will I incur any charges if these files are less than 90 days old?**

When you copy objects to Backup2, you will be storing another copy of the data. Therefore, you will be charged for this additional storage at whatever storage class it is using. When you restore objects from the Glacier storage class, they are temporarily stored as Reduced Redundancy Storage. You'll have to check what storage class is used after you copy the files to Backup2.

**Will the copy be done from Glacier to Glacier or will it be from Glacier to S3 Standard?**

To copy objects from Backup1, you will need to first **Restore** the object(s) from Glacier. Once they have been restored, they will be available in S3.

**Since this involves file copy from Glacier, will it be time consuming?**

The file copy is fast, but you will first need to **restore** from Glacier. You can choose how long this should take, depending on whether you wish to pay for an expedited retrieval (1-5 minutes) or standard (3-5 hours) or bulk (5-12 hours).